# Pandas split/extract string within brackets with exception

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, replace, split

I am stuck with a specific problem, which is best explained by several examples:

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd
items=["ga - bg - cg - dg", "ag - bg - cg (u i)","ag - bg - cg ","ag - bg - cg - d g(u i)","ag - bg - cg (u i(u i))","ag - bg (ui)","ag - bg - cg (ATO) - dg","ag - bg - cg (ATO) (dg)"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['R'],data=items)
```

#----------------------------------

```
0          ga - bg - cg - dg
1         ag - bg - cg (u i)
2               ag - bg - cg 
3    ag - bg - cg - d g(u i)
4    ag - bg - cg (u i(u i))
5               ag - bg (ui)
6    ag - bg - cg (ATO) - dg
7    ag - bg - cg (ATO) (dg)
```

- I want to split the strings into 4 parts (by ' - '),
- extract everything in brackets into the last column, except (ATO),
- and remove the outer brackets.

The end result should look like this:

```
0          ga - bg - cg - dg  ga  bg        cg        dg
1         ag - bg - cg (u i)  ag  bg        cg       u i
2              ag - bg - cg   ag  bg        cg        cg
3    ag - bg - cg - d g(u i)  ag  bg        cg  d g(u i)
4    ag - bg - cg (u i(u i))  ag  bg        cg  u i(u i)
5               ag - bg (ui)  ag  bg      None        ui
6    ag - bg - cg (ATO) - dg  ag  bg  cg (ATO)        dg
7    ag - bg - cg (ATO) (dg)  ag  bg  cg (ATO)        dg
```

So far I came up with this code:

```
df[['R.1','R.2','R.3','R.4']]=df['R'].str.split(' - ',n=3,expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
splits=df['R'].str.split(' - ',n=3)
lastelem=splits.str[-1]
NoBrackets=df['R'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
df[['R.1','R.2','R.3','false']]=NoBrackets.str.split(' - ',n=3,expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
df.drop(['false'],axis=1, inplace=True)

splitNum=splits.agg([len])
for index,item in lastelem.iteritems():
    n=splitNum.iat[index,0]
    if n!=4:
        df.iat[index,-1]=lastelem[index].split('(',1)[-1].rsplit(')',1)[0].strip()
print(df)
```

#-----------------------------

```
0        ga - bg - cg - dg  ga  bg    cg        dg
1       ag - bg - cg (u i)  ag  bg    cg       u i
2            ag - bg - cg   ag  bg    cg        cg
3  ag - bg - cg - d g(u i)  ag  bg    cg  d g(u i)
4  ag - bg - cg (u i(u i))  ag  bg    cg  u i(u i)
5             ag - bg (ui)  ag  bg  None        ui
6  ag - bg - cg (ATO) - dg  ag  bg    cg        dg
7  ag - bg - cg (ATO) (dg)  ag  bg    cg  ATO) (dg
```

I'm sure there must be a simpler way to achieve what I've got but I'm not getting there at the moment.
Also I don't know how to 'save' the exception (ATO) to be removed.
Please let me know if I missed anything in the explanation of my problem and let me know how to improve my code.

Comment: Why is the output in row 2: `ag  bg        cg        cg` you are repeating the `cg`

Comment: Oh yes, I did'nt see that one. It should be (None).

Comment: I tried it like this, but it results in other issues:
`reportEntWithoutBracets=df['R'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
df[['R.1','R.2','R.3','R.4']]=reportEntWithoutBracets.str.split('-',n=3,expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
# adapt special case 'Germany - Other - Flight Crew Training organisation (ATO)'
df['R.3'][df['R'].str.contains('(ATO)')] = 'Flight Crew Training organisation (ATO)'
stringInBrackets=df['R'].str.split('(',n=1).str[1].str.rsplit(')',n=1).str[0]
df['R.4']=df['R.4'].str.cat(stringInBrackets,na_rep='').str.strip()
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a solution with the nested parenthesis mask from @Dani Mesejo

Thanks for the hint!

```
withoutBracets=df['R'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
df[['R.1','R.2','R.3','R.4']]=withoutBracets.str.split('-',n=3,expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
# adapt special case 'Germany - Other - Flight Crew Training organisation (ATO)'
mask_ato = df['R'].str.contains('(ATO)', na=False)
df_noATO=df['R'].str.replace(r'\(ATO\)','')

# split string on first ( and join with delimiter 
stringInBrackets=df_noATO.str.partition('(')[[1,2]].agg(''.join, axis=1)

# concatenate 
df['R.4']=df['R.4'].str.cat(stringInBrackets,na_rep='').str.strip()

# nested parenthesis mask
mask = df['R.4'].str.startswith('(', na=False)
# remove parenthesis only when nested
df.loc[mask,'R.4'] = df.loc[mask,'R.4'].str[1:-1]

# re-add (ATO) to string
df.loc[mask_ato, 'R.3'] = df.loc[mask_ato, 'R.3']+' (ATO)'

print(df)
```

Result:

```
0        ga - bg - cg - dg  ga  bg        cg        dg
1       ag - bg - cg (u i)  ag  bg        cg       u i
2            ag - bg - cg   ag  bg        cg          
3  ag - bg - cg - d g(u i)  ag  bg        cg  d g(u i)
4  ag - bg - cg (u i(u i))  ag  bg        cg  u i(u i)
5             ag - bg (ui)  ag  bg      None        ui
6  ag - bg - cg (ATO) - dg  ag  bg  cg (ATO)        dg
7  ag - bg - cg (ATO) (dg)  ag  bg  cg (ATO)        dg
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
# split by the last space that is not preceded by -
df[['head', 'tail']] = df['R'].str.strip().str.split(r'(?<!-)\s+(?=\S*$)', expand=True)

# split the first part by -, strip trailing -
head = df['head'].str.strip(' -').str.split(' - ', expand=True)

# copy tail
tail = df['tail'].copy()

# drop head and tail from original data
df = df.drop(['head', 'tail'], 1)

# join head and tail
data = pd.concat((head, tail), axis=1)

# use only the first not None value
data.iloc[:, 3] = data.iloc[:, 3].combine_first(tail)

# drop tail from data
data = data.drop('tail', axis=1)

# nested parenthesis mask
mask = data.iloc[:, 3].str.startswith('(', na=False)

# remove parenthesis only when nested
data.loc[mask, 3] = data.loc[mask, 3].str[1:-1]

# concat with original data
res = pd.concat((df, data), axis=1)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
                         R   0   1         2       3
0        ga - bg - cg - dg  ga  bg        cg      dg
1        ag - bg - cg (ui)  ag  bg        cg      ui
2            ag - bg - cg   ag  bg        cg    None
3    ag - bg - cg - dg(ui)  ag  bg        cg  dg(ui)
4    ag - bg - cg (ui(ui))  ag  bg        cg  ui(ui)
5             ag - bg (ui)  ag  bg      None      ui
6  ag - bg - cg (ATO) - dg  ag  bg  cg (ATO)      dg
7  ag - bg - cg (ATO) (dg)  ag  bg  cg (ATO)      dg
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did'nt include all cases in the example dataframe. The parts inside the brackets can be phases with spaces inbetween words aswell. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @codingNewbie The phases will be always surrounded by parenthesis?

Comment: Like shown in the examples phrases can be without parenthesis, but then they will be following the third ' - '. For example:
`ag - bg - cg - d g(u i)`
should result
`ag     bg      cg     d g(ui)`
or
`ag - bg - cg - d g`
should result
`ag     bg      cg     d g`